# Detecting Potential MacBook Pro Hardware Damage

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, high-sierra

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) and my sister was angry for some reason when using it. Suddenly, she closed the MacBook with so much force that I could hear a thud. At the time, she was sitting down on a bamboo mat through which she slid the device.

I took the MacBook Pro and checked for visible damage. Luckily there was none! Running a hardware test returned `No Issues found`, but I was still not satisfied, hence my post.

**Question:** *Should I worry about hardware damage at this point?*

**Additional Information**
When I was scrolling through Safari history, I saw one specific history flashing. I deleted that history and the flashing decreased to a very small (2cm) spot before going away after the deletion. *Although I doubt it, is this a related hardware issue?*

Comment: Mistreating a laptop in various ways is *always* concerning. But if there is no physical damage and diagnostics show ok it is **likely** OK. But sometimes damage does not show up until repeated incidents of abuse.

Comment: Generally much more severe "drop tests" are performed as part of the standard certification process of a product like a Macbook.  I would not personally be concerned as long as you see no damage, and the diagnostics are all OK.  Basically, I support what @SteveChambers said.

Comment: @SteveChambers thanks for your answer. I support what you say too. But I have a feeling that the aluminum body will save the crucial components and the MacBook did not fall down. It was slid on a bamboo mat

Comment: I have posted this question in my Guest account by mistake. So I replied with my main account.

Comment: @SteveChambers  I have another question my sister one time was carrying two things in her hand so she needed the MacBook at the same time so what she did was insane she took the MacBook put it in between her knees and started walking. So can this abuse damage my MacBook? I am just super paranoid!

Comment: @nobody You can [merge your accounts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 1):

take it to an apple store, ask for a thorough examination, and give them a tip for their time.

THEY will know what's wrong with it, and since they are trained to sell you NEW devices, they will be extra motivated to find the smallest thing wrong with it.

I get it, parents bought me an refurbed iphone one time (gave it to my sister) and I went to the apple store to get it analyzed to make sure it was good.

Answer (score 0):

> I took the MacBook Pro and checked for visible damage. Luckily there
>   was none! Running a hardware test returned No Issues found, but I was
>   still not satisfied, hence my post.
>
> Question: Should I worry about hardware damage at this point?

**If it looks good, it is good.**

Your early 2015 MacBook Pro has virtually no moving parts save the fan, hinges and keyboard.  **Everything** is is solid state.

[image]

This means that if your MacBook Pro looks undamaged, hinges and keyboard work then your MacBook Pro is fine.  If the fan was damaged, you would get an error.  If anything on the logic board was broken/damaged, you would know immediately as you would be getting errors/failures.